# Google SpreadSheets Timestamp for IMPORTDATA

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

What I tried to accomplish is a Google AppScript, which automatically gives me a Timestamp, whenever a cell withing a certain range changes. The certain range is for example Sheet1, col 1-89:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (r.getColumn() < 90 && ss.getName()=='Sheet1') { 
var celladdress = 'CT' + r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

When Sheet1 contains an IMPORTDATA feed; does this even work? Because my timestamp did not change since I implemented the script.

Thank you!

Comment: Only **user** edits can trigger an `onEdit` trigger so the answer to your question is no. You can't trigger an `onEdit` function via formula or script etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your IMPORTDATA is refreshed from an active worksheet, then yes it will allow you to update a timestamp value.

You can use the event object passed to onEdit here rather than check the active cell. If the edited cell is one that you want to track, then set a timestamp. Something like this:

```
function onEdit(event) {
var r = event.range
var ss = r.getSheet()
if (r.getColumn() < 90 && ss.getName()=='Sheet1') { 
var celladdress = 'CT' + r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question.

Comment: I have edited it. If the user refreshes the importing data, this will in turn will trigger the onEdit, no?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :) Does this also work if you have a .csv link in the import data? Because this would be the next step.

Comment: I think it would, but better try to check! If the answer helps, please consider marking it as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work, but thank you anyway! :)